Run GitHub action to update pull request with files ignored into .gitignore
I have the following workflow:
name: Update Documentation
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'roles/*/defaults/main.yaml'
      - 'roles/*/Chart.yaml'
      - 'roles/*/README.md.gotmpl'
concurrency:
  cancel-in-progress: true
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Documentation
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install package
        env:
          HELM_DOCS_URL: https://github.com/norwoodj/helm-docs/releases/download
          HELM_DOCS_VERSION: 1.14.2
        run: |
          sudo wget -qP /tmp $HELM_DOCS_URL/v${HELM_DOCS_VERSION}/helm-docs_${HELM_DOCS_VERSION}_Linux_x86_64.deb
          sudo apt-get -y install /tmp/helm-docs_${HELM_DOCS_VERSION}_Linux_x86_64.deb
      - name: Update documentation
        run: helm-docs --values-file=./defaults/main.yaml
      - name: Update pull request
        run: |
          git config user.email '${{ github.actor_id }}+${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com'
          git config user.name '${{ github.actor }}'
          git add -fA ./roles/*/README.md
          git commit -am 'docs(github-action): Update documentation'
          git push origin ${{ github.ref_name }}
permissions:
  contents: write

and .gitignore:
/roles/*/README.md

My goal is to update the README.md files with the above GitHub action only. Currently, this is the action error output:
  git config user.email '19806285+user@users.noreply.github.com'
  git config user.name 'user'
  git add -fNA ./roles/*/README.md
  git commit -am 'docs(github-action): Update documentation'
  git push origin 290/merge
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
* (HEAD detached at pull/290/merge)
[detached HEAD 0f6c2f0] docs(github-action): Update documentation
 2 files changed, 635 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 roles/argocd/README.md
 create mode 100644 roles/certmanager/README.md
error: src refspec 290/merge does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/org/user'

I did some research on the src refspec 290/merge does not match any error and is unclear to me what is the missing step to address the issue. It is suggested to create a new branch with the -M switch but I find this unnecessary, since the branch already exists when the action is triggered on current pull request.
I believe the problem is with the git add step, files are not added to the refspec. Thank you for your suggestions.
Edit: The only way I was able to fix the issue is with the following code execution:
git config user.email '${{ github.actor_id }}+${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com'
git config user.name '${{ github.actor }}'
git fetch
git switch ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }} <-- actual branch name e.g. renovate/victoriametrics-victoria-logs-single
git add -fA ./roles/*/README.md
git commit -am 'docs(github-action): Update documentation'
git push origin ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}

If I fetch and switch to branch github.event.pull_request.head.ref, everything works as intended. Personally, it does not makes sense to me performing these steps, when I do a checkout action, I should have all branches already fetched. If you could provide some insight, it will be appreciated.

If you're actually trying to update the ref, then perhaps you need to use pull/290/merge instead of 290/merge. (But in general it feels strange to try to push to that directly rather than updating the source branch. I don't know if you can actually do that, and if you can, what side effects it would have.)

These README updates are done with Renovate, so they don't interact with a working developer branch. Please see the edit I added into OP, I'm still trying to understand why a fetch is required. Basically, I did what you suggested.

Try git push origin HEAD instead

You push to github.ref_name. For a pull request, that's a special ref where a "test merge commit" is done, and it looks like <pr_number>/merge.
You want to push into the head branch of the pull request: that's github.head_ref.
